# Calendar.MONTH setting to wrong month

Tags: java

```
 //this month
        SimpleDateFormat df_formonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5); //integer to be changed upon click - maybe month counter from now
        String currmonth = df_formonth.format(c.getTime());
```

This should return June since we index months from 0 to 11

but it returns july

any solutions or other ways to fix this?

Comment: Please give a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: try - df_formonth.format(new Date());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because today's date is the 31st of August and June only has 30 days, the month is automatically incremented to the following month giving July.

To solve you can set the date before setting the month

```
c.set(Calendar.DATE, 30);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JUNE);
```

Also I suggest using `Calendar` constants for clarity

Comment: This behaviour ("auto-wrapping") can be prevented by using `Calendar.setLenient(false)`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That would result in an `IllegalArgumentException` being thrown...

Comment: I know. I depends on the requirements if that would be desired or not. I just wanted to mention the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Well known issue when you are working with dates at the end of the month (31st of Aug).
You should explicitly set the date.

For example read here for details:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/385083/java/java/java-util-Calendar-set

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.clear();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JUNE);
```

Comment: the question is not actually about June